# Routing between 3 interfaces in 3 separate networks

Tags: firewall, routing, redhat, nat, mikrotik

### Prologue

Greetings network engineers out there! I would appreciate your help in following scenario. I did some research, and I figured out only two solutions. And because one of them is not suitable for me, I need your help with the second.

---

### Environment

I have 2 devices with 3 interfaces in total. Each interface is in different VLAN. Here is an overview:

```
Name: DevA
Type: Red Hat Enterprise Linux (v7)
Interface #1: eth0
Interface #1: xxx.xxx.215.222
```

and

```
Name: DevB
Type: MikroTik RouterOS v6.42
Interface #1: ether1
Interface #1: zzz.zzz.214.128
Interface #2: ether2
Interface #2: yyy.yyy.216.92
```

Here we go with more details:

- Each of the 3 interfaces have public static IP address.
- Each of the 3 interfaces have access to internet.
- There are services running on DevA (let's say on ports 666 and 999 for example).

---

### Goal

- DevB is accessible from internet only on **ether1**.
- Devices DevA and DevB are communicating with each other only through dedicated interfaces (**eth0** and **ether2**).
- Services on DevA are accessible only through DevB, not directly from internet.
- If DevA wants to reach something in the internet (updates, for example), it must be reachable directly. Means, if DevA initiates connection, it goes directly to the internet.
- Services on DevA have to be visible for public with DevB's **ether1** IP address (if possible).
- > VPN betwen DevA and DevB is **not allowed**. This is solution which I mentioned earlier, and which is not suitable in this scenario. I will consider this only if there is no other option.

---

### What do I have already

**DevA - Firewall cofiguration**

```
- allow all outgoing traffic on eth0
- allow all incoming traffic from ether2 to eth0
- allow all related and established connections
- drop everything else
```

**DevA - Routing configuration**

```
dst-address          pref-src            gateway           distance
0.0.0.0/0                                xxx.xxx.215.1     1
xxx.xxx.215.0/24     xxx.xxx.215.222     eth0              0
```

**DevB - Firewall cofiguration**

```
- allow all outgoing traffic on ether1 and ether2
- allow incoming traffic on ether1 for ports 666 and 999 
- allow all incoming traffic from eth0 to ether2
- allow all related and established connections
- drop everything else
```

**DevB - Routing configuration**

```
dst-address          pref-src            gateway           distance
0.0.0.0/0                                zzz.zzz.214.1     1
zzz.zzz.214.0/24     zzz.zzz.214.128     ether1            0
xxx.xxx.215.0/24                         yyy.yyy.216.1     1
yyy.yyy.216.0/24     yyy.yyy.216.92      ether2            0
```

---

#### So, can you help me solve this puzzle?

I expect more routes have to be configured on DevB (maybe NAT/masquerade as well?) and probably on DevA, too. Any ideas? If I forgot to mention something, just ask..

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud write a DNAT rule to forward traffic from DevB to DevA, and also a good idea to write a SNAT/MASQUERADE in DevB to make the forwarded traffic return back to DevB and then to Internet. 
like this:

> DNAT :

```
 ip firewall nat add chain=prerouting protocol=tcp dst-address=zzz.zzz.214.128 dst-port=666,999 action=dst-nat to-addresses=xxx.xxx.215.222
```

> SNAT :

```
ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat dst-address=xxx.xxx.215.222 action=masquerade
```

> BTW, It would be wise putting the 2 interfaces that should be connected to each other on devices to same Vlan and using invalid IP addresses to make them communicate with each other. (If possible!)

Comment: Thank you. I’ll configure what you suggested later on. I’ll keep you up to date :-)

Comment: It works; thank you for pointing me right direction. Actually, I think about the last part you mentioned: `BTW, It would be wise putting the 2 interfaces that should be connected to each other on devices to same Vlan and using invalid IP addresses to make them communicate with each other. (If possible!)` - can you explain further please?

Comment: I'm talking about DevA eth0 and DevB ether2, These two may not need to have Public IPs, if the interfaces are for communication between the devices.